# matlab Pythagorean Theorem without using for

Tags: matlab, pythagorean

I am doing a matlab homework and I solved the next problem. and the grader say it is a correct answer. I used for in the program and we didn't take yet in the course. can someone suggest a program with out for or if.

Write a function called pitty that takes a matrix called ab as an input argument. The matrix ab has exactly two columns. The function should return a column vector c that contains positive values each of which satisfies the Pythagorean Theorem, a2 + b2 = c2, for the corresponding row of ab assuming that the two elements on each row of ab correspond to one pair, a and b, respectively, in the theorem. Note that the built-in MATLAB function sqrt computes the square root and you are allowed to use it.

my code

```
function c = pitty(ab)
    [n , m] = size(ab)
    for i = 1:n
        c(i) = sqrt(ab(i,1)^2 + ab(i,2)^2)    
    end
    c = c'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can square each element of the matrix by using the `.^2` operator. Then summing along each row `sum(...,2)` and finally taking the root.

```
ab = [1,2;3,4;5,6]

c = sqrt(sum(ab.^2,2));
```

No `for` needed for that.

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB has a function for this called [`hypot`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hypot.html) short for [hypotenuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotenuse). The main reason for existence of it is that it takes care of overflow (and underflow) problem. If the input values are too large (or small) the square of them (or sum of square of them) can be larger (smaller) than the largest (smallest) representable value in floating-point, while still the corresponding `c` value is representable. In your case you can use it like this:

```
c=hypot(ab(:,1), ab(:,2));
```

Cleve Moler, one of the founders of MathWorks and original author of MATLAB, tells the story behind `hypot`in [this article](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2012/07/30/pythagorean-addition/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend `hypot` as in [Mohsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30095637/2586922).

Just for some variety, here's another approach, using complex numbers. This approach **avoids overflow and underflow**, just like `hypot` does:

```
abs(ab*[1; 1j])
```

Examples (taken from [Cleve Moler's post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2012/07/30/pythagorean-addition/)):

```
>> ab = [1e154 1e154];        %// LARGE VALUES: possible overflow
>> sqrt(sum(ab.^2,2))
ans =
   Inf                        %// overflow
>> hypot(ab(:,1), ab(:,2))
ans =
    1.414213562373095e+154    %// correct result
>> abs(ab*[1; 1j])
ans =
    1.414213562373095e+154    %// correct result

>> ab = [3e-200 4e-200];      %// SMALL VALUES: possible underflow
>> sqrt(sum(ab.^2,2))
ans =
     0                        %// underflow
>> hypot(ab(:,1), ab(:,2))
ans =
    5.000000000000000e-200    %// correct result
>> abs(ab*[1; 1j])
ans =
    5.000000000000000e-200    %// correct result
```

Comment: It seems like someone (downvoter) doesn't like complex numbers for this task :-) Perhaps I should add that this is not probably the preferred approach; I just wanted to provide some alternative. But note that it does avoid overflow, just like `hypot`.  I've edited my answer to include this information

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought that `abs` of a complex number would be a simple `sqrt(real(X).^2 + imag(X).^2)` as written in the doc ... but it seems they included overflow protection there too.